# How to change vlc-qt media display widget?

Tags: qt, vlc-qt

I am using [vlc-qt](https://vlc-qt.tano.si) to build a simple media player. And at first I connect the player to a widget, and it works, but when I tried to use the `setVideoWidget` member function again to change the display widget, it seems doesn't work,  so what should i do? Is this member function `setVideoWidget` can only be called once?

[image]

I have call `setVideoWidget` in my constructor `_player->setVideoWidget(ui->video);` to                    set the video widget(the black one you can see in the image above) as the default widget to play media and it works.

But when I tried to change the display widget to another one (named as `anotherWidget`,  the green one you can see in the image above)

```
void SimplePlayer::on_changeButton_clicked()
{
    _player->pause();
    _player->setVideoWidget(ui->anotherWidget);
    _player->play();
}
```

When I clicked the button named `changeButton` it changes nothing.The media was still displayed on the default video widget(the black one).

My constructor:

```
SimplePlayer::SimplePlayer(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent),
      ui(new Ui::SimplePlayer),
      _media(0),
      _equalizerDialog(new EqualizerDialog(this))
{
//  init ui
    ui->setupUi(this);

    _instance = new VlcInstance(VlcCommon::args(), this);
    _player = new VlcMediaPlayer(_instance);
    _player->setVideoWidget(ui->video);


    signals & slots......



}
```

Comment: Hi there! Is it possible to attach your code to your question? It's difficult for us to guess what you are trying to do. A [_minimal, complete, and verifiable example_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will help a lot. Thanks!

Comment: Well, and I have updated my description:)